# returning 2 values within a function

Tags: c++

I am trying to return values (namely rows and columns) upon a file read, and since I will be reading in multiple files and getting the same variables from each file, I thought it will be better for me to write a function rather than copying and pasting duplicate codes.

Anyway, I am trying to return 2 values and to use them too, please see my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int r(string fn);

int main()
{
    int a, b = r("input_a.txt");

    cout << "a --- " << a << endl;
    cout << "b --- " << b << endl;

}

int r(string fn)
{
    ifstream fin01;
    string file = fn;

    fin01.open(file.c_str());

    ...
    ...
    ...

    // Suppose I should be getting 2 for 'rows' and 3 for 'cols'
    return rows, cols;
}
```

I got `0x7fff670778ec` and `0x7fff670778e8` for my output instead...

Any pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot return two values from a function that is declared to have a single `int` as return type:

```
int r(string fn){
    /*...*/
    return rows,cols;  // <-- this is not correct
}
```

Also the way you call this function is not behaving as you might expect:

```
int a, b = r("input_a.txt");
```

this declares two integers and initializes the second one with the return value of the function, but the first one stays uninitialized (see [TerraPass answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645926/4117728) for more explanation on the comma operator).

You basically have two options. First option is to pass references to the function and the function assigns the results to those references:

```
void r(string fn, int& rows,int& cols) {
    /*...*/
    rows = x;
    cols = y;
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
int a,b;
r("someString",a,b);
```

However, in this way the caller has to "prepare" those return values. Imho it is more convenient to use the return value to return results from a function (sounds logical, no?). To do this you just have to define a type that encapsulates the two integers:

```
struct RowAndCol { int row;int col; };

RowAndCol r(string fn) {
    /*...*/
    RowAndCol result;
    result.row = x;
    result.col = y;
    return result;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
RowAndCol rc = r("someString");
```

Note that you could also use a `std::pair<int,int>` instead of defining your custom struct (see e.g. [molbdnilos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647101/4117728)). However, IMHO whenever you know exactly what is contained in the pair, it is better to give it a reasonable name (e.g. `RowAndCol`) instead of using a naked `std::pair<int,int>`. This will also help you in case you need to add more methods to the struct later (e.g you might want to overload the `std::ostream& operator<<` for your struct to print it on the screen).

PS: Actually your output does not look like it was produced by the code you are showing. Theses are some memory addresses, but in your code there is neither a pointer nor an address-of operator.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're used to Python (I peeked at your profile), but the comma does not create a pair in C++.

(You may not have thought about it that way, but you can only return one value from a Python function, too. If you "return two values", you're returning *one* pair.)

Fortunately, there are tuples in the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>


std::pair<int,int> r(std::string fn);

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> result = r("input_a.txt");
    cout << "a --- " << result.first << endl;
    cout << "b --- " << result.second << endl;

// Or,
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    std::tie(a, b) = r("input_a.txt");
    cout << "a --- " << a << endl;
    cout << "b --- " << b << endl;


}

std::pair<int, int> r(std::string fn)
{
    std::ifstream fin01(fn);

    // ...

    return std::make_pair(rows, cols);
}
```

Comment: yea, I have been using python previously and hence you can say that I have mixed myself up between python and c++ in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in C++ cannot return multiple values of their return type via a `return` statement.

---

```
int a, b = r("input_a.txt");
...
return rows, cols;
```

These 2 lines don't do what you think they do.

The line `int a, b = r("input_a.txt");` is equivalent to:

```
int a;
int b = r("input_a.txt");
```

That is, you declare variables `a` and `b` and initialize `b` to the return value of `r("input_a.txt")`, while `a` remains uninitialized.

The line `return rows, cols;` is equivalent to:

```
rows;
return cols;
```

...and is an example of [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which evaluates its left operand (in your case, `rows`), discards the result, then evaluates its right operand (in your case, `cols`) and returns the result of this evaluation. So, in effect, your function `r()`, as it is now, always returns a single value, `cols`.

---

If you need to return more than one value from a function, you should consider accepting additional arguments as non-const references for you to store resulting values to, or changing the return type of your function to some `struct`, which would contain all of the values you want to return. You can find an example of both these approaches in @tobi303's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645711/1051764).