# (Qt) How to use a value from another function?

Tags: c++, qt

So here's my issue. I'm making an extremely simple game in Qt, but I'm having trouble increasing the difficulty in the game. For example, once your score hits a certain value, you level up. In game the text changes and says Level 2, but the game doesn't get any harder. I have the idea to achieve this by making the enemies move faster. I have the enemies moving at a predefined value, but I want the position change to be equal to the value "speed" in Level.cpp. The answer is probably staring me in the face, but it's the simplest answers that always get me. Below is a header and 2 source files that connect Level.cpp and Enemy.cpp.

**Enemy.cpp**

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QList>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "Game.h"
#include "Level.h"

extern Game * game;

Enemy::Enemy(QGraphicsItem *parent): QObject(), QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent){
    //set random x position
    int random_number = rand() % 700;
    setPos(random_number,0);

    // drew the rect
    setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/enemy.png"));
    setTransformOriginPoint(50,50);

    // make/connect a timer to move() the enemy every so often
    QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));

    // start the timer
    timer->start(30);
}

void Enemy::move(){
    // move enemy down
    setPos(x(),y()+7);
    //Instead of 7 above, use speed from Level.cpp

    // destroy enemy when it goes out of the screen
    if (pos().y() > 600){
        //decrease the health
        game->health->decrease();
        scene()->removeItem(this);
        delete this;
    }
}
```

**Level.cpp**

```
#include "Level.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <QFont>

Level::Level(QGraphicsItem *parent): QGraphicsTextItem(parent){
    // initialize the score to 0
    level = 1;
    speed = 5;
    // draw the text
    setPlainText(QString("Level: ") + QString::number(level)); // Level: 0
    setDefaultTextColor(Qt::green);
    setFont(QFont("times",16));
}

    void Level::LevelUp(){
        level++;
        speed = speed+2;
        setPlainText(QString("Level: ") + QString::number(level)); // Level: 1
    }

    int Level::getLevel(){
        return level;
        return speed;
    }
```

**Level.h**

```
#ifndef LEVEL_H
#define LEVEL_H

#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

class Level: public QGraphicsTextItem{
public:
    Level(QGraphicsItem * parent=0);
    int getLevel();
    void LevelUp();
    int speed; //speed is public because I got "int is private" errors on a few things I tried.
private:
    int level;
};

#endif // LEVEL_H
```

Thanks for any help, and if possible in-depth explanations on what you did to solve the issue.

EDIT: Would my issue be trying to send out Speed, but being unable to because the Level function is labled as a `QGraphicsTextItem`? Will I just need to create a separate function to increase speed?

Comment: `Level::getLevel()` -> you cannot return from a function more than once

Comment: So would making a new function in Level.cpp returning only speed and calling it in Enemy.cpp solve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [returning 2 values within a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645510/returning-2-values-within-a-function)

Comment: Why would `Level::getLevel()` return `speed` anyways?

Comment: actually this question is not an exact duplicate of the above, it is based on a similar misunderstanding, but here you should provide a separate getter method, yes

Comment: @JarrodA., dunno, but seeing two successive `return`s in a function makes me think you're missing some fundamental things. Also, you never call neither `getLevel` nor `LevelUp`

Comment: @ForceBru LevelUp is called in score.cpp, which isn't listed above, and is used in Game.h, which Enemy.cpp uses as a header. getLevel is also called there, and I have the same sharing headers thing from Game.h, such as the health int in Enemy.cpp

Comment: I mean, if you return from a function, then it literally goes to nowhere: it's literally _'executed'_. Once it `return`s, it can do nothing more, so your `return`s look like a giant flaw in the logic.

Comment: @tobi303 The game works as is, no issues at all, I'm just taking the next step. I only included 2 files out of 9 that I have. The game is finished per say, just adding a challenge :)

Comment: @ForceBru I use `return level;` just like I do in a few other files, like the Health and Score, returning those values so that the math to increase or decrease them can update the value and output it to Game.cpp to be displayed, I'm sure there are easier ways to accomplish this, or maybe my method is unnecessary, but that's how I accomplished it.

Comment: @JarrodA. srry, it was a quite stupid comment and I will delete it in a second. I was just trying to tell you that you are obviously missing some c++ basics (no offense) and me and others might be able to clarify things and the sarcasm was a bit misplaced...

Comment: @tobi303 No offense taken, I didn't take your comment aggressively or think it was sarcastic, I just didn't want to post every file I had to bloat the question with unneeded code.

Answer (score 0):

not sure which design pattern you are using, but sounds you need a controller to control enemy object. So basically whenever level is changed the level obj should tell the controller, well now enemy should increase speed. Then the controller will notify the enemy.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction to accomplish that?